# Man Made ELS Codes

Tags: steganography

This is more steganography, not cyptography, but I don't know where else to post this.

Are you familiar with ELS (Equidistant Letter Sequence) codes that some have said are found in the Bible? I know the Bible codes are probably fake, but I am wondering if it is possible for humans to encode ELS codes in natural sounding text, preserving style, clarity, brevity, and flow. Can someone provide an example of this being done, and recommend some methods for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

ELS is basically numerology, with letters. It's not a term recognized by the cryptographic community, although it *is* possible to encode information in natural-sounding text, depending how it's done and whether the recipient knows the encoding scheme. Whether or not you'd be able to tell that it's there without an obscene amount of sample text, on the other hand, I wouldn't know.

An example technique would be the use of synonyms. Whenever there is the opportunity for use of a synonym or alternative wording where either word is equally appropriate, the specific word chosen can encode information. I could have used "equally appropriate" or "equally acceptable" in the previous sentence, but I went with the former. They both sound natural. Did I encode a simple boolean value by using the former instead of the latter phrasing, or was it chance that I wrote what I did?